# Put 3 elements in a row, should not break when resized

Tags: html, css

In the picture is what I am trying to achieve.

[image]

When resized, inner elements should stay as they are:

[image]

This is what I tried:

```
<div style="width:100%;text-align:center;">
    <div style="width:80%;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;">
        <div style="float:left;">
        </div>
        <div style="float:left;">
        </div>
        <div style="float:left;">
        </div>
        <div style="float:left;">
        </div>
        <div style="float:left;">
        </div>
        ...
    <div>
</div>
```

But when I resize it, it get like 2 in a row, or 5 in a row, depending on how I resize the screen. Should be 3 all the time, centered. Width of inner elements not to be changed.

Comment: Inner divs with red border have fixed width in px all the time? How much is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add classes if you can.  HTML:

```
<div class="one">
    <div class="two">
        <div class="three">
        </div>
        <div class="three">
        </div>
        <div class="three">
        </div>
        <div class="three">
        </div>
        <div class="three">
        </div>
        ...
    <div>
</div>
```

...and CSS:

```
<style>
.one {width:100%;text-align:center;}
.two {width:Npx;margin: 0 auto;"}
.three {width:31%;margin:1% 10px;height:100px;float:left;box-sizing:border-box;}
.two .three:nth-of-type(3n + 1) {clear:left}
</style>
```

the inner div's need a fixed width (here, 1% on right and left) for a total width of 33%.  Fixing height makes this work for variable content, otherwise, it looks off.  The "nth-of-type) selector is a failsafe in case you can't use a fixed height.

Elaborating on using a fixed height, if you decide to parse your output with javascript to hide certain elements, they will still be counted in the "nth-child" iterative loop, which would break your layout.  Using a fixed height and exact percentage widths should almost always work.

You'll note that there's 1% left over, but it's small enough not to be an issue.

**EDIT:**
Edited to add box-sizing:border-box;.  Setting the box-sizing to border-box will include any added padding or border thickness to size, because if you add padding without it, your layout will break.

**EDIT 2:**
Reviewing OP's question, there is a requirement for the inner content to maintain a fixed width.  The only way to do that is to declare a fixed with for .two or .three.  Declaring a fixed width for .three will not center the content without additional css manipulation, so add a fixed width to .two.

Please note that a fixed width is a terrible idea for rendering in mobile, if your application needs that.  I would suggest using a media query as follows, and swapping to the more popular two column layout for mobile:

```
<style>
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) { /* or whatever width... */
.two {width:auto;margin:auto;}
.three {width:46%;margin:2% 10px;}
.two .three:nth-of-type(3n + 1) {clear:none} /*cancels above */
.two .three:nth-of-type(odd) {clear:left} /* every two, clear left */
}
</style>
```

This will get you on the right track....